# execute 'sudo su' command in rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am developing Rails v2.3 app. and using MySQL v5.1 on **Ubuntu** machine.

I have a **rake** task to **stop** and **start** mysql database like following:

```
namespace :db do
  task :some_db_task => :environment do
       ...

       exec 'sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop'
       ...
       exec 'sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start' 
  end
end
```

As you see above in the code, I used `sudo` to make sure the command get executed. However, because of this `sudo` , when I run the **rake** task, **there will be a prompt ask me to input root password** though the rake task get run successfully.

I want to avoid the password input thing, so I thought I could execute shell command to firstly change to root user, then stop/start MySQL, so I changed my code to following:

```
namespace :db do
  task :some_db_task => :environment do
       ...

       exec 'sudo su'
       exec '/etc/init.d/mysql stop'
       ...
       exec '/etc/init.d/mysql start' 
  end
end
```

See, I added `sudo su` command to be run firstly. Now I run my rake task again, **but, suprisingly the rake task run until** `exec 'sudo su'` **then it stopped**, the rest code does not even get run. Why? How to get rid of it?

(Generally, I do not want to input root password during the rake task running for MySQL start and stop)

Comment: `sudo su` wil spawn an interactive terminal as `root`, and wait for you to play with it. You're trying to solve your problem in the wrong way, if you need `root` privileges, you WILL need a password (or your set-up is terribly unsafe).

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5866632/execute-a-sudo-command-in-ruby-on-rails-app

Comment: `sudo su` is a strange way of saying `sudo -s`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have several problems.

First, the [Kernel#exec](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-exec) method won't return. See the API description:

> Replaces the current process by running the given external command.

Second, it's really weird to execute `sudo` from Ruby. Could you simply execute `sudo rake db:some_db_task`?

**UPDATED**

Third, `Kernel#exec` won't return, but `Kernel#system` will. If you really want to `sudo` in your rake script, you need to use `Kernel#system` and execute `sudo` in every command. Ex:

```
   system 'sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop'
   system 'sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start'
```

`system 'sudo su'` doesn't work. It will start a shell with root user, and when you leave the shell, the Ruby process won't gain root permission.

Comment: Thank you, if I plan to execute sudo rake db:some_db_task, then, inside my rake task do I need to have sudo on each command or not?

Comment: `sudo` flips the process to root-level, so all subsequent subprocesses of that are root unless specifically down-graded.

Comment: @tadman: Yes, sudo will flip the process to root-level. However, in this scenario it will only affect child process of rake. The remaining command in the Ruby script won't be affected. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Use "system" is the right choice for my rake task as exec won't return the process, I just notice that all the code after exec is not run. Thank you Miaout

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend creating shell aliases for the two commands instead.  Rake tasks in Rails were not really intended to do system specific things.

Add these lines to your .bashrc to make it quicker to start and stop.

```
alias mysql_start = 'sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start'
alias mysql_stop = 'sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop'
```

If you're looking to do this as a deployment type of situation, [capistrano](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/) is better suited for the work.

Comment: You can also add that command to `/etc/sudoers` to not require a password for certain user accounts.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use sudo for rake not for custom command (i.e. sudo rake db:some_db_task)?
or try call exec 'sudo su' first time, other executable without 'sudo', but i think rake can run exec every time for new session and sudo su command was closed on next exec.

Some link about this problem
http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/69967

Comment: Thank you, if I plan to execute sudo rake db:some_db_task, then, inside my rake task do I need to have sudo on each command or not?

Comment: Now i can't test it, but i think sudo not need more because exec run into sudo rake process and rake process all ready have sudo privelegies